# Laravel 5.4, Passport, and Angular 7 not playing nicely together

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-passport

I've got a site that I've built using Laravel 5.4 that I'm working on updating the UI on. I want to go in the direction of a Single Page Application using Angular 7. However I'm stuck trying to make a request to my API endpoint I keep getting a 401 error. I've followed the instructions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript added the meta tag to the page, did the additional setup, and started using Angulars HTTP library like so

```
this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.meta.getTag('name=csrf-token').content
    })
};

this.http.get('api/v1/people', this.httpOptions).subscribe((data: any) => {console.log(data); });
```

however I continue to receive the 401 error. In addition here are the Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,       
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api'
    ],
];
```

and Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
     Route::get('people', 'personController@apiIndex');
     Route::get('person/{id}', 'personController@apiGetPerson');
     Route::post('contactevent', 'contactEventsController@apiAddContactEvent');
   });
});
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood some of the documentation provided. When you want to consume your api through javascript that you serve up on your site you don't have to include your route in the `auth:api` group to authenticate the call. Laravel instead passes a cookie with your request additionally CSRF isn't needed unless it's a POST request. My solution was to move my route to the `auth` middleware group like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('api/v1/people', 'personController@apiIndex');
}
```

And to rewrite my Angular HTTP request like so:

```
this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
};

this.http.get('api/v1/people', this.httpOptions).subscribe((data: any) => {console.log(data); });
```

And everything worked as expected.